# STDIN Pipe file into for loop

Tags: bash

I was wondering is there a way that i can enter

```
./myscript.sh FILENAME
```

and the file will link into

```
for a in $(cat FILENAME) ; do
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling your script with:

```
./myscript.sh babynames
```

You can process each line of you file with `read`:

```
while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
done < "$1"
```

Comment: so I would like the ability to each time a run the script I have to tell it what file to use. I.E. how do make it so the file isnt actually coded in to the script. instead I have to run it like $ bash myscript.sh | babyname

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I will but first could you explain what the $1 does

Comment: `$1` refers to the first argument of you calling script, `babynames` in that case.

Comment: seeing as you seem very smart do you know what i need to add to name="${babyname#*:}" to remove the space at the end of this line    "girl:sarah "

Comment: I would apply a second parameter expansion `babyname=${babyname% }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat > myscript.sh                        # create myscript.sh
for i in "$(cat $1)" ; do echo "$i" ; done # in the end CTRL-d
$ cat > babynames                          # create babynames
primo
secundo                                    # in the end CTRL-d
$ bash myscript.sh babynames               # execute the script with babynames as parameter
primo
secundo
```

Comment: so lets say my script is called myscript and the tile I would like to input and read line by line is babynames how would i structure that ?? Thx sorry I am very new to this

Comment: Sorry that isnt doing what i need. Infact all that did was write over my script

Comment: Please, in your question be more specific on what is the input and expected output. Also, think before you act, `create myscript.sh` means just what it says. Sorry about your script, though.